# R, mapping items in a data frame

Tags: r, function, operator-keyword

Total newb here. Please explain how on Earth does this line work, I understand the rest:

```
 gene_symbol <- id2symbol$gene_symbol[id2symbol$Ensembl == gene_id]
```

How does the `==`, which as I know equals TRUE, work in this case? Or does it mean something else here? Thank you ever so much!

```
cancer_genes <- c("ENSG00000139618", "ENSG00000106462", "ENSG00000116288")

id2symbol <- data.frame(
  "Ensembl" = c("ENSG00000141510", "ENSG00000139618", "ENSG00000106462", "ENSG00000116288"),
  "gene_symbol" = c("TP53", "BRCA2", "EZH2", "PARK7")
)

gene_id_converter <- function(gene_id) {
  gene_symbol <- id2symbol$gene_symbol[id2symbol$Ensembl == gene_id]
  return(gene_symbol)
}

gene_id_converter(gene_id="ENSG00000141510")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the function, we can either `Vectorize` or loop over the elements to get the value

```
sapply(cancer_genes, gene_id_converter)
```

-output

```
ENSG00000139618 ENSG00000106462 ENSG00000116288 
        "BRCA2"          "EZH2"         "PARK7"
```

---

`==` is elementwise operator i.e. it should either have the lhs and rhs to be of same length or the `rhs` can be of length 1 which gets recycled.  The output of `==` is a logical TRUE/FALSE which is used for subsetting the corresponding value from `id2symbol$gene_symbol`.

Thus, if we provide more than one element to the function, there will be a length difference and it can get unexpected results due to recycling

```
> id2symbol$Ensembl == cancer_genes[1]
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> id2symbol$Ensembl == cancer_genes
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In id2symbol$Ensembl == cancer_genes :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thus by looping over the `cancer_genes`, it would use the single element to recycle and gives back a logical TRUE/FALSE and get the corresponding `id2symbol$gene_symbol` where there are `TRUE` elements

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I am still somewhat confused. Please have a look at these two lines of code:                                                                                                gene_symbol <- id2symbol$gene_symbol[id2symbol$Ensembl == gene_id]                                 gene_symbol <- id2symbol$gene_symbol[which(id2symbol$Ensembl == gene_id)]                    They give the exact output, but how? WHICH returns an index position and that makes total sense. But in the first example, the expression in the parenthesis gets evaluated to TRUE, and then what?

Comment: @Trubulica `id2symbol$Ensembl == gene_id` returns TRUE/FALSE vector as I showed.  Extraction (`[`) of elements for gene_symbol will be based on the TRUE values i.e. positions having TRUE values from the logical vector is returned for gene_symbol.  Not sure how I can explain it more.

Comment: I thought so. So what is the reason for using WHICH? When you use WHICH, you only return the index number, but when you use just the Boolean without WHICH, you return the element itself?

Comment: @Trubulica That is related to the property of `==` i.e. if there are `NA` (missing values), the `==` returns `NA` instead of TRUE/FALSE for that position and with `[`, it will be a missing value.  In that case, `which` would be useful, as it removes those `NA` or you can use `%in%` instead of `==` (which is not elementwise)

Comment: @Trubulica you can try `v1 <- c(1, 3, 5, NA); v2 <- 3;  v1 == v2#
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA; which(v1 == v2)#
[1] 2; v1 %in% v2#
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: Wonderful. It finally clicked in place, I didn't understand the fact that if you select/extract from a data frame (in this case) with a Boolean you get the paired element returned. It's so simple that I had to make it complicated in my head :) Thank you a lot, now I can move on with my studying.